# How to run hadoop commands in Spark 3.0?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I installed Spark 3.0 prebuilt with Hadoop 3.2 using brew on mac os. I can run spark-shell command but I get command not found error when I run hadoop command.

If I have to install hadoop separately after having installed above, does that mean I have duplicate two versions of hadoop installed on my system? Or I have to uninstall spark prebuilt with hadoop and re install spark without hadoop and somehow figure out how to connect spark to hadoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running Hadoop commands or any other Hadoop's component, you need to install Hadoop explicitly.

May be [this](https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/big-data/how-to-install-hadoop-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan.html) can help you install hadoop on Mac OS

> Reply to updated question

You will not have two different Hadoop versions.
Let me put it in other words, your Spark 3.0 is built with Hadoop 3.2, which means your spark is compatible with Hadoop 3.2 but this does not mean your hadoop is packaged within spark binaries or it will be auto installed with spark installation, you need to install Hadoop 3.2 explicitly. Because they are two different software packages.

For connection between Hadoop's HDFS and Spark, you can set an environment variable `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/your/hadoop/conf/dir` (Linux command). Then, your spark jobs will start referring to your hadoop configurations and know based on what configuration to connect to Hadoop.

For example, post configurations this code `sparkSession.read.text("/hdfsfile.txt")` will be read from Hadoop's HDFS .

Comment: Hi, You can revisit the answer. Updated.